# Convert from a "vector<vector<float>>" to a "Mat" type openCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, fft, dft

I have to evaluate the FFT of a vector vector float (named 'raggio') and I wolud save the result in DFT_raggio.

```
vector<vector<float>> raggio,DFT_raggio;


DFT_raggio.resize(raggio.size());
for (int i = 0; i < raggio.size(); i++)
{
    DFT_raggio[i].resize(raggio[i].size());
    cvFFT(&raggio[i], &DFT_raggio[i], DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT, 0);
}
```

I tried using cvFFT but in the execution the code stops with errors.

**UPDATE:** Is there a way to copy the content of a single vector of a vector vector float in a Mat type?

Comment: What exception is it exactly?

Comment: It's in Italian, I hope you understand anyway: Eccezione non gestita in corrispondenza di 0x00007FFE01473C58 in OpenCV3.1VS2015Win10.exe: Eccezione Microsoft C++: cv::Exception in corrispondenza della posizione di memoria 0x00000088A6CFDF40.

Comment: I think it's about memory allocation

Comment: Looks like memory access violation. Are you sure you have to pass the ADDRESS of your vectors? I can't find documentation for cvFFT, but it feels odd. Try A: comment out the cvFFT part and see if it's not your vector resizing (doubt it) and B: uncommnet cvFFT but remove the '&' symbol from vectors.

Comment: Also, I think your output will be vector of complex numbers instead of just floats so I doubt the result will be just vector<float> from cvFFT

Comment: Vector resizing it's ok. Removing & from vectors in cvFFT gives me this error: 
Error (active)  Does not exist any convertion function from "std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>" to "const CvArr *" OpenCV3.1VS2015Win10 c:\Users\Marco\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OpenCV3.1VS2015Win10\OpenCV3.1VS2015Win10\Origine.cpp 89

Comment: I've checked the documentation:      DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT performs a forward transformation of 1D or 2D real array; the result, though being a complex array, has complex-conjugate symmetry (CCS, see the function description below for details), and such an array can be packed into a real array of the same size as input, which is the fastest option and which is what the function does by default; however, you may wish to get a full complex array (for simpler spectrum analysis, and so on) - pass the flag to enable the function to produce a full-size complex output array.

Comment: it's a wild shot, but try replacing &raggio[i], &DFT_raggio[i] with raggio->at(i) and DFT_raggio->at(i). I really don't like that & symbol, and I've never seen an OpenCV function that would take pointer instead of reference...